# jquery-ui tab "Interactive controls must not be nested"

Tags: accessibility, jquery-ui-tabs

I use jquery-ui tabs. Sample code:

```
<ul role="tablist">
 <li role="tab"><a class="label" href="#tabs-1" aria-label="Description tab">Description</a></li>
 <li role="tab"><a class="label" href="#tabs-2" aria-label="Reviews tab">Reviews</a></li>
 <li role="tab"><a class="label" href="#tabs-3" aria-label="Credits tab">Credits</a></li>
 <li role="tab"><a class="label" href="#tabs-4" aria-label="Cataloging tab">Cataloging</a></li>
</ul>
```

The axe-core DevTools accessibility checker flags a "serious" problem with this code: "Interactive controls must not be nested", with the explanation "Interactive control elements must not have focusable descendants" and referencing guideline WCAG 4.1.2.

The problem, as I understand it, is that there is a link inside the listitem. From a Github discussion for axe-core (https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core/issues/601), the clickable link within the list item causes issues with screen readers.

But this seems like a standard use of the jquery-ui tab widget. How I do change the tabs widget code to make it accessible?

Answer (score 4):

The items within `<ul role="tablist">` will have `tabindex="0"` etc. added to them in order to make them focusable (the actual `li`, not the link) and then the anchor should have `tabindex="-1"` added to it.

The idea is that the link is a fallback for if JS fails, this is why it is included in the first place and isn't just plain text.

However this does indeed cause nesting of interactive elements as you now have `tabindex="0"` on the list item (making it "interactive" / focusable) and then a link within it.

They add `tabindex="-1"` to the link to remove it from the focus order, but some screen reader / browser combos will still pick this link up and this is why it is flagged.

So there is a workaround but you will need to implement it yourself.

First, add `role="none presentation"` to the link:

```html
<li role="tab"><a class="label" href="#tabs-1" role="none presentation">Description</a></li>
```

What this does is signal that this anchor should be treated like a `<div>` or a `<span>` as far as assistive technology is concerned (it removes all semantic meaning).

Secondly, (but you would have to check it works with jQuery-UI) would be to remove the `href` attribute from the link **via JS** (so it is only removed once the Tab component has initialised).

You should end up with the following if you inspect the elements after doing this (ignoring any classes added etc.):

```html
<li role="tab"><a class="label" role="none presentation">Description</a></li>
```

This will stop it being a focusable item if JS works and loads correctly, but will fall back gracefully if JS fails to load.

Also notice I removed your `aria-label` as the fact you are using a `role="tab"` already tells a screen reader that it is a tab so your label was not needed.

So in summary:

- add `role="none presentation"` to the links within the `<li>`
- remove the `href` attribute from the links via JavaScript.
- remove the `aria-label` (not related to the problem)

This should make the tabs as accessible as possible within jQuery-UI, but there may be other problems with it so I can't say whether it is accessible or not!

Comment: I found that adding `role="none"`, removing the `href` attribute, and also removing the `tabindex` attribute that jquery-ui adds did indeed squash "Interactive controls must not be nested" error that axe-core flags. However, it looks like the `href` is critical to the tabs widget -- the tabs don't work after removing it. I tried using an onclick instead, but that didn't work, and there are console log errors from jquery-ui without the `href` tag.

Comment: Looking through the source code there's no way to change the structure of the tab. It requires a [ul element](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/main/ui/widgets/tabs.js#L401) and requires the ul to have an [li with an anchor element with href attribute](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/main/ui/widgets/tabs.js#L425). With that in mind I'm not sure you could hack the tab creation in such a way that would make it accessible. You'd have to remove some stuff after the fact to make it work.

Comment: Does it actually hook into the `href` element once initialised or does it just need it as part of the setup? If you can't remove the `href` then it will not be possible to remove this error, but you will have done everything you can within the library constraints with the other suggestions. Obviously the purist in me says to find an accessible library, but in the real world it is not always possible, so just do the best you can, in reality only a few screen reader users will have an issue if you implement the `role="presentation none"` part.

Comment: There's a lot of times in the code where it references the `href` specifically to get information, but I'm not sure on jQuery UI lifecycle events to know when they would be triggered. For example, if the [`_refresh` function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/main/ui/widgets/tabs.js#L320-L322) is triggered, then they would require the `href` attribute still. You'd have to do some extensive testing to make sure you could get away with changing things after the fact to make sure functionality didn't break.

Comment: Using `role="none presentation`[ I think this is the correct order, since "presentation" is a fallback role more widely supported than the "none" role, per [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#presentation)] on the `<a>` tag is flagged as "ARIA roles used must conform to valid values" and also "ARIA role should be appropriate for the element"; changing to `role="presentation"` eliminates the "conform to valid values"; but flags a new issue that the role conflicts with "other roles" which I think refers to global attribute of the `<a>` tag? Or maybe a problem with the axe tool.

Comment: @unknownrisk thank you so much for pointing out my goof! I have fixed it (and am now wondering whether I have made that mistake elsewhere and am now examining every project to make sure I haven't ).

Comment: So, the only way to make this accessible AND maintain the ability to execute the URL on the <a> tag is to create a javascript function that executes the navigation to that url when someone "clicks" the tab itself and not the <a> tag? That is wild.

Comment: @Loopy you work with what these old frameworks give you. Much better to roll your own component and attach the handlers to the right places when you can!