# Primefaces TabView generates Axe DevTools compliance issue

Tags: primefaces, tabview, axedevtools

I'm trying to setup a Primefaces TabView

```
    <p:tabView >
        <p:tab title="Title">
            Content
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
```

and the generated html produces the following Axe DevTools compliance error:

"Interactive controls must not be nested"

"Ensures interactive controls are not nested as they are not always announced by screen readers or can cause focus problems for assistive technologies"

With a link to this page for more information: https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/4.8/nested-interactive?application=AxeChrome

It highlights this part of the generated HTML:

```
<li class="ui-tabs-header ui-state-default ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true" data-index="0" tabindex="0">
  <a href="#j_idt425:j_idt426" tabindex="-1">Title</a>
</li>
```

"To solve this problem, you need to fix the following:"
"Using a negative tabindex on an element inside an interactive control does not prevent assistive technologies from focusing the element (even with aria-hidden="true")"

Related Node

```
                <a href="#j_idt425:j_idt426" tabindex="-1">Title</a>
```

My reading is the problem is having a focusable element (`<a.. ></a>`) inside another focusable element (`<li>...<li>`).

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

I see the related issue here, but working through Primefaces I can't fine tune the generated HTML: [jquery-ui tab "Interactive controls must not be nested"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70857293/jquery-ui-tab-interactive-controls-must-not-be-nested)

Using Primefaces 10.

Comment: Please check if you can reproduce with the latest version. If so, please create an issue https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues